# Обновление страницы в java servlet (jsp)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Вопрос в следующем, есть java сервлет и скриплет (jsp) с javaScript. На сервере происходит обновление в файловой системе, а на jsp это отображается отправляя Get запросы с интервалом в 2 секунды на другой jsp, где идет проверка последнего времени обновления содержимого, если новое, то подгружаем из файла новое содержимое. Насколько плохо такое решение и есть ли альтернативные подходы?

Comment: Можете переформулировать вопрос? > _на jsp это отображается отправляя Get запросы с интервалом в 2 секунды на другой jsp_ - вот это вот совсем непонятно

Comment: > _идет проверка последнего времени обновления содержимого_ - каким образом происходит проверка? Отправкой запроса на сервер?

Comment: Какой сервер используется? Tomcat, Jetty, что-то другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормальное решение. Простое и легкое, и не требует особых затрат в производительности и большого количества интернета. Я в своей практике достаточно часто сталкивался с таким способом проверки обновлений/статусов/и т.п.